# Unable to see git branch structure using gitk -all or git log --graph

Tags: git

I'm just learning git version control using this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/easy-version-control-with-git/

Now I made 2-3 commits, then made and switched to a different branch. Then I made 2-3 more commits.

But I still see a simple straight line in `gitk -all` or `git log --graph`.

What could be going wrong?

```
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git add .
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git commit -m 'first commit'
[master (root-commit) d525eb9] first commit
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 file1
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git add .
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git commit -m 'second commit'
[master 5fe0bba] second commit
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 file2
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git branch branch1
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git checkout branch1 
Switched to branch 'branch1'
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git add .
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git commit -m 'branch commit1'
[branch1 84e162e] branch commit1
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 branchfile
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git add .
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git commit -m 'branch commit 2'
[branch1 bb7a619] branch commit 2
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 branchfile2

user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git status
# On branch branch1
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
user@comp:~/Documents/trygit2$ git log --graph
* commit bb7a619990925782c37921e80c3aaf8310530de2
| Author: = <=>
| Date:   Fri May 17 16:33:58 2013 +0530
| 
|     branch commit 2
|  
* commit 84e162e186dc1a7d51ac48eaf3d05748178da803
| Author: = <=>
| Date:   Fri May 17 16:33:42 2013 +0530
| 
|     branch commit1
|  
* commit 5fe0bbaf72b3db9f456c5687efd425b0dac28466
| Author: = <=>
| Date:   Fri May 17 16:32:50 2013 +0530
| 
|     second commit
|  
* commit d525eb935deb4899293db64bdbc350add21bc943
  Author: = <=>
  Date:   Fri May 17 16:32:28 2013 +0530

      first commit
```

Comment: The command is `gitl --all`. Note the double --.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong. You have a straight commit line:

```
A-->B-->C-->D-->E-->F
        ^           ^
   BranchA        BranchB
```

If you now checkout `BranchA` and make some commits, you will see the branches diverge in `gitk --all`

Answer (score 1):

This is because your commit history can be displayed in a straight line.

```
* 5 (HEAD, my-branch)
* 4
* 3 (master)
* 2
* 1
```

It gets interesting if you commit something to master

```
* 6 (HEAD, master)
| * 5 (my-branch)
| * 4
|/
* 3
* 2
* 1
```

This can not be displayed in a straight line anymore.